# Install Ubuntu Netbook remix on existing karmic 9.10 installation

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, ubuntu-netbook-remix

I've tried installing the Ubuntu Netbook Remix on my netbook, but the installer wouldn't work. I've now installed regular Ubuntu 9.10. Is there any way to transform this into the netbook edition?

When looking through the documentation, I saw that you can basically add a PPA source and install some packages, but that this is outdated and not for 9.10.

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just do

```
apt-get install netbook-launcher
```

... that's that. It will come from the Universe repository, so you will need that enabled (I think it is by default in 9.10, anyway). Once it's installed, you should have an option in Preferences to switch the interface type.

Note: I haven't tried this. My netbook installed UNR just fine.

Comment: That installs the menu/desktop thingy, but I needed 5 or 6 more packages and to edit the main panel.

Comment: I also couldn't get the netbook installer to boot on my netbook so I installed the normal 9.1 image. 

I tried installing netbook-launcher but I get the error "E: Couldn't find package netbook-launcher".
Do I need to add a repository?

Comment: actually i needed to perform an update after installing.

Answer (score 2):

Try System > Administration > Synaptec Package Manager.

Then Edit > Mark packages by task...

Select Ubuntu netbook Remix, and apply.

For more info: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=7489558&postcount=13

Comment: Synapt**i**c. Small detail.

Comment: I had the same problem as the questioner so I installed the normal version of 9.1 on my netbook. When I go to "Mark packages by task" there is no option for netbook remix - any idea why?

Comment: i had to perform an update after installing and then i was able to select the netbook remix task. is it possible to deselect the desktop task? its checked but greyed out so it seems im stuck with the desktop stuff